# Alien Speices with extreme day/night cycle

Tags: aliens, day-night

I am creating this alien species and they live on three separate worlds blah blah, that doesn't matter right now.

This one planet I have has a fairly long day-night cycle (I haven't decided on how long yet) that would make the planet extremely hot during the day and really cold in the night. There isn't much water on the planet so there wouldn't be any snow or anything. (living here is more a pride thing than living comfy)

Could they survive being warm blooded?

They are an advanced race, like space travel kind of advanced so if they have to create their own protection it's not a big deal for them.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Following sun = no buildings/nomads. Advanced race creating protection = buildings/cities. Don't these ideas contradict?  [Are they on floating cities](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cloud_City)?

Comment: I didn't read what I wrote carefully enough. I meant to delete the part that they follow the sun, sorry. 
It would get up to at least 150 in the day and probably like -70 at night in Fahrenheit.

Comment: By the time a given species can travel between worlds, they can live anywhere. Space is far more hostile towards life than just about anything else. They'd probably build below-ground cities for insulation, and come out when it's comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

## Humans already do this.

Desert climates have extreme variation in temperature every day. They quickly rise to temperatures like 120 Fahrenheit during the day and then fall to below freezing during the night.

And humans have lived in climates like this for ages.

Because this is an alien species we are talking about, it is very reasonable to say that they could have evolved to be able to survive through greater variations in temperature than even humans can.

---

## Another idea.

You previously stated (before editing the question) that they might follow the sun. This gave me an idea.

Perhaps, over the ages, as they followed the sun these aliens slowly created structures that span around the world in a straight line. Perhaps they no longer need to follow the sun because the structures are finally complete, and protect them from the harsh cold?

Answer (score 1):

**We do OK with temperature extremes.**

St.Louis has weather pretty much as you describe and you can live in the same house all year.  It would be nice to have a thermostat that automatically switched between air conditioning and furnace instead of you having to pick HEAT or COOL, because you would probably use both in a day.

Ideally a house like this would be attached to a big thermal reservoir, like a tank of water under the house or a big rock.  The water tank would also be nice if there were no much water around, so you would not run out.  Heat energy could be captured during the say and then used to warm the house at night.  Insulation would be a must.  Or build underground.

The lawn would be tricky.  You might need a reflective cover, like a pool cover except it would be called a lawn cover.  You could also have a pool cover if you had a pool.  .

Totally a doable deal with a tiny bit of tech.  Not even Star Trek tech.  Like 1970s tech.  And 1970s clothes.